# Nearby places not showing up?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I have this code that should create markers with nearby places to an already existing marker, on a google map. My map and original market ( not in this code ) work fine, but the nearby places seem not to.

```
<script type="Javascript">
    function showFood(marker) {

        var request = {
            location: marker.position,
            radius: '1000',
            query: 'food, college, library, gym, bar'
        };
        map: map;
        service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        service.textSearch(request, callback2);
    }

    function callback2(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            for (var i = 0, result; result = results[i]; i++) {
                console.log("Results:");
                console.log(result);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: result.geometry.location,
                    console.log(position);
                    title: "",
                    visible: true
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                        showFood(marker);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Any help would appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: fix the syntax-errors

Comment: "Nearby Seaarch" is NOT the same as "Text Search". See "[difference between a nearby search and a text search in Google Places API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620053/difference-between-a-nearby-search-and-a-text-search-in-google-places-api)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop looks odd, should be something like this

```
for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
...
}
```

Also when are you first calling showFood as I can only see it in your callback function. I guess you are calling it after you create the initial marker? If you are not then your code you have posted never gets called.